# I can't make my activity dialog

Tags: android, android-studio

i am watching a tutorial which defined this theme to make my activity dialog

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

but when i do that , the application made error
when i open it on avd, it says `unfortunately, "applicationName" has stopped`
here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

should i extends from another class or what should i do ?

Comment: `but when i do that , the application made error` which error?

Comment: add FULL logcat to see where the mistake

Comment: the application doesn't start    when i tried to open it,this message appeared " unfortunately, "applicationName" has stopped"

Comment: If you don't add relevant information we can't help you.. For example the Logcat output or the layout XML code (R.layout.activity_main). Without enough information my guess will be that you don't use a Toolbar element in your layout XML + maybe your Theme doesn't support an action bar

Comment: relative information like what ?
I've wrote everything

Answer (score 0):

Try this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` in your manifest.

For more read [AppCompatDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDialog.html)

Comment: i can't find it , but this is too close
Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog
 but give me
the same error
when i tried to open it,this message appeared " unfortunately, "applicationName" has stopped"

Comment: if you want to use Theme.Dialog then you should change your appcompact activity to activity, but using this you wont be able to use FAB button and other support library stuff.

Comment: try this <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" />

Comment: the same problem
'unfortunately, "applicationName" has stopped'

Comment: i can't find this theme, but when i tried this 'Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog ',it gave me the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer .. replace this theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

with this

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`